# Multiple controlling Fields for single dependent field

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, dependent-picklist

I have 3 pick-list fields: picklist 1,picklist 2,picklist 3.
 picklist 1 is the controlling field for picklist 2.
 picklist 2 is the controlling field for picklist 3.

As per the requirement,  picklist 3 should show values according to what i have  choose on picklist 1,picklist 2. so basically picklist 3 need 2 controlling fields, picklist 1,picklist 2.

How to get this , through apex and visual force?

Comment: You don't need apex. Just use the [dependent picklists](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_defining_field_dependencies.htm&language=en_US&type=0).

Comment: Write custom logic to display 3 field in Visualforce page and on change of each call apex:actionSupport to call apex method to rerender the appropriate picklist's option.